# is there an abstraction layer for XML?

Tags: php, xml

i wonder if there is a good abstraction layer for XLM like ORM for databases?

is it a good solution or is it better to use simple_xml for xml CRUD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you can use Apache's [XMLBEANS](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/). For PHP, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263771/generate-php-classes-from-xsd) Stack Overflow question.