# Broadsoft over soap

Tags: zend-framework, soap

does anyone has experience with Broadsoft with php or zend framework? I have to access a Broadsoft platform with zend framework over soap, but there is no wsdl file...
Regards Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wimzel and idanek both basically hit it on the nail.  I've been developing for Broadsoft BroadWorks for about 6 years now.  Broadsoft treats everything as an OCI Command.  In the Java or C# world, you'd rely on BroadSofts provided XSD schema paying particular attention to the release version matching your BroadSoft servers version - with java you'd then use xml-beans or jax-b to read in the XSD schema and generate your java code in C# you'd use xsd.exe.  In the case of Broadworks R20SP1 this generates roughly 4300 java classes O_o.  I've also done the same thing using C#.

If you cant migrate from PHP to Java or C#, this previous question may give you some help or lead you on to other searches
[generate PHP classes from XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263771/generate-php-classes-from-xsd)

Note - technically you can just create a raw TCP socket on port 2208 (default), authenticate, login (all using OCI "Commands") and use the same J-Session Id for all subsequent calls if done in a timely manner.  You *can* create all the OCI commands XML from scratch - but if you were trying to create a provisioning system or something this may be quite painful.  Generally at the simplest provisioning a group, user and phone in Broadsoft is a minimum of about 15 API calls/commands

Comment: any sample for c#? I am struggling now....I did the part you said "technically" now and its very painful...

Comment: @Wangsu OCI-P is far quicker to use for provisioning or manipulating broadsoft braodworks users and groups than OCI over SOAP/web services but unfortunately BroadSofts example client JAR is obviously Java so cant easily be used with C# - with that said are you looking for a OCI over SOAP example - I might be able to "whip" something up for you

Answer (score 4):

For the most part, the Broadsoft/Broadworks WSDL file sits at this URL (WITH YOUR DOMAIN)

`http://YOURDOMAIN/webservice/services/ProvisioningService?wsdl`

Answer (score 1):

That is the first step, second step is to create OCI-P messages from XSD shema.